# $watch not executing the first time the value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript

I've got 2 controllers which communicate through a shared service, where as one of them watches a value on the service for changes. However, it only works after the second time the value has changed - what could be the cause of this?

```
export interface ISharedService {
    value: customObject;
}

class SharedService implements ISharedService {
    value: customObject;
}

export class Controller1 {

    private sharedService : ISharedService;

    constructor(sharedService : ISharedService) {
        this.sharedService = sharedService;
    }

    changeValue(value: customObject) {
        this.sharedService.value = value;
    }

}

export class Controller2 {

    constructor($scope : ng.IScope, sharedService : ISharedService) {
        $scope.$watch(() => sharedService.value, (prev, cur) => {
            if(prev !== cur) {
                alert("WEEEEEE!");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

When I'm now changing the value from the view by calling the `.changeValue()` function, nothing happens. After the second the time the function is called, it suddenly starts working.

Answer (score 0):

I actually took your code, added the missing parts, and it works for me.

here's the html:

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="Controller1 as vm">
        <div>changeCounter={{vm.changeCounter}}</div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="Controller2 as vm">
        <div>sharedService.value={{vm.sharedService.value}}</div>       
        <button ng-click="vm.onClick()">Click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's the code:

```
class SharedService {
    value: string;
}

class Controller2 {

    private sharedService;
    constructor(private sharedService) {
        this.sharedService = sharedService;
    }

    onClick():void {
        this.sharedService.value = Math.random();   
    } 
}

class Controller1 {
    changeCounter = 0;
    constructor($scope, sharedService) {
        $scope.$watch(() => sharedService.value, (prev, cur) => {
            if(prev !== cur) { 
                this.changeCounter = this.changeCounter + 1;
            }
        });
    }

}

angular.module("myModule", [])
.service("sharedService", SharedService)
.controller("Controller1", Controller1)
.controller("Controller2", Controller2);
```